# Mapbox GL JS `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]

Tags: geometry, geolocation, coordinates, mapbox-gl-js

Hello I am using Mapbox GL JS but I am struggling displaying the map. I am having two issues:

1. It says coordinates are undefine.
2. Says Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: , lat: }, an object {lon: , lat: }, or an array of [, ]

My show page have the following script:

```
<script>
    const mapToken = '<%-process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
    const campgroundGeometry = '<%- JSON.stringify(campground.geometry) %>'
</script>

<script src="/javascripts/showPageMap.js"></script>
```

My showPageMap file have this:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = mapToken;
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10', // stylesheet location
center: campgroundGeometry.coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 8//
})

new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat(campgroundGeometry.coordinates)
.setPopup(
    new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 })
        .setHTML(
            `<h3>${campground.title}</h3><p>${campground.location}</p>`
        )
)
.addTo(map)
```

I can see I am successfully getting the coordinates from the location in the Sources in my console through the campgroundGeometry function but I dont know what I am missing in my showPageMap page.

Here is an example of what I get in Sources:

```
const campgroundGeometry = '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.419906,37.779026]}'
```

My map shows as a grey square in the app.

I am new to all this, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
const campgroundGeometry = '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.419906,37.779026]}'
```

You have a string. You need an object.

Try this:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat(JSON.parse(campgroundGeometry.coordinates))
```